# Certificate only works from client side, how do I debug something like this? (graylog/filebeat/JVM keystore)

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, logstash, graylog, filebeat

I created 2 key-certificate pairs with the exact same method. However, while trying to setup TLS on my graylog server to a remote filebeat node, it does not successfully connect when trying to connect with a regular certificate validating the authenticity of the graylog server.

Then, if disable server side TLS but I enable client authentication, it miraculously works and I have a TLS connection. I have no idea how to debug this? I have checked the files are readable by the user, mounted into the container, correct path. I also turned the filebeat authentication all the way down to only check validity and not domain, in case there was some spelling issue or other with the domain name.

I have tried wireshark and there is some TLS activity going on but honestly my knowledge is very limited with certs. Do I really have to become an expert on the handshake to add a simple TLS?

I am using the certificate as its own CA which worked fine for the client authentication.